# vim: having tabs in a single viewport

Tags: vim, tabs

I would like to have two viewports, one with Nerdtree and the other with tabs of the files I'm editing. Is this possible? Whenever I try to split and then opening tabs I get one tab with 2 viewports and one tab with only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab pages contain windows which contain buffers. You can't have a tab page inside a window.

Maybe there is [a plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) that sort of does what you want but I'd recommend *not* taking that path and, instead, learn to use buffers, windows and tab pages *as they are meant to be used.*

Vim is vastly smarter and more powerful than whatever you used before switching. Trying to adapt it to your old habits is quite possibly the worst strategy you could come up with.

Related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs/26710166#26710166) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331664/how-to-show-tab-close-button-in-gvim/21338192#21338192).

Comment: This. Once you get used to buffers, you end up almost never using tabs.